# Saddle choice for long distance rides

Tags: saddle, long-distance

Every year I travel home to Nice, on my own, from a European capital with my bike ex. Paris, Salzburg, Naples, etc. 
Last year I started off from Madrid, and this year from Berlin; both of these trips took me nine days (~1500 kms).

I ride a Giant Defy Advanced bicycle equipped with disk brakes and Zipp 303 wheels.

My current saddle, ASTUTE Skylite, replaced the original Fizik saddle that came with the bicycle; I was told that most manufacturers equip their bikes with 'lesser' versions of saddles in order to trim the overall cost.

Previously I rode a TREK fitted with a Selle Italia saddle.

Sizewise I'm 1,72m and 68kgs

I wear an Assos T.Cento bib designed for long distances (purchased 2015) and apply copious amounts of Assos chamois cream

In preparation, during the year, I cycle once a week 60-80k with at least a 500m climb

My main difficulty during these trips is my back side

The sit-bone area becomes swollen with a sore on each side which gets understandably quite painful; Compeed and Doliprane/Neurofen are my only recourse

Each evening I wash my clothes with shampoo in my hotel room

Having adopted a vegan diet I have also chosen to avoid leather based products.

I'm still searching for THE saddle that will allow me to pursue such trips without the suffering.

I'm currently considering a Brooks C15 (or C13 145) saddle

Should I accept that it is the mileage and duration of these trips, or even lack of preparation, that are to blame for my plight and will remain thus whatever saddle I may choose ?

cheers

Comment: That's a really cool series of rides! :-) The problem can't be _only_ that you're cycling 1500km in nine days, since the pros do that two and a half times back-to-back without much of this kind of problem. However, you already know that you need a saddle that suits your own backside and I don't think we can help you any more with that: we don't do product recommendations and we couldn't possibly give such a personalized recommendation anyway.

Comment: The pros also practice year round. How did you prepare for these trips?

Comment: Thanks for your responses
I go out for a 60k ride once a week, whicj usually includes a 500m climb

Comment: 60km once a week isn't that much compared to 150km per day 9 day straight. I'd recommend practicing more and getting used to sitting in saddle.

Comment: Thanks all for your contributions

My research has brought me to look at the Well model developped by Selle SMP 

The resellers are able to lend you a saddle in order to try it out for a few days, which is exactly what I plan to do

Comment: Probably not your problem, but for people whose butts are not as well "conditioned" as yours going in, a big problem is butt hair.  As you ride the hairs get tangled, often including tangles between the two "halves" of the butt.  Then (*surprise!*) when you get off the bike and walk the hairs are pulled out by the roots.  The solution is either to bike more often (and thus take care of the problem a little at a time) or, a few days before your ride, shave the area, being especially careful to get hairs near the "crack".  (Don't do this the night of the ride unless you use an electric razor.)

Answer (score 2):

Get your sit bones measured.

Bikes are made in different sizes, handlebars in different widths, cranks and stems in different lengths, seat tubes are adjustable.  Why all this variation?  Because people are built differently.  So why just choose a saddle that "should be good" and go?  Get your sit bones measured, then buy a saddle from a company that makes different width saddles to accommodate different riders anatomy accordingly.

Comment: Having tested the Drakon, I finally settled on the Selle SMP Well